# ANOVA of Model Performance metric

Tags: anova, modeling, model-evaluation

I have conducted multiple simulations of a hydrological model under a matrix of scenarios and calculated a Nash-Sutcliffe Efficiency (NSE) value for each simulation. The NSE is a model performance metric similar to the R2 and more information can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel_Moriasi2/publication/43261199_Model_Evaluation_Guidelines_for_Systematic_Quantification_of_Accuracy_in_Watershed_Simulations/links/0c96052853e7733fd9000000/Model-Evaluation-Guidelines-for-Systematic-Quantification-of-Accuracy-in-Watershed-Simulations.pdf).

After looking at my results it seemed like it was the perfect set up for a two-way ANOVA. However, the input data would be only the 9 NSE values listed in the table below.

I want to know if the performance (NSE stat) is different among different Ksat (calibrated, measured, and ROSETTA PTF) and if the performance is different among SWCC (measured, Vereecken PTF and ROSETTA PTF). This could be done separately for the drainage and overflow rows.

My concerns are: 
1) each combination only has three values each. Is this enough data? How could we assume normal distribution?
2) what does comparing means tell us about a performance statistic?

[image]

Comment: Whose software is this, please?

Comment: It's a new model that's not available online. Is there a reason you are asking? Maybe I can answer

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. The terminology used is specialized enough that I do not know, and cannot find what is being referred to, e.g., NSE stat. I would suggest defining terms, including links, and clarifying what is being asked so that the question becomes a bit clearer for people who are reading it. I thought that if perhaps there was some package documentation I could read that, but, no such luck.

Comment: This paper describes the Nash Sutcliffe Efficiency [link] (https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel_Moriasi2/publication/43261199_Model_Evaluation_Guidelines_for_Systematic_Quantification_of_Accuracy_in_Watershed_Simulations/links/0c96052853e7733fd9000000/Model-Evaluation-Guidelines-for-Systematic-Quantification-of-Accuracy-in-Watershed-Simulations.pdf). It describes model outputs compared to measured values. It is similar to an R2 but ranges from negative infinity to 1 with 1 being the optimal value. An NSE of 0 means that the mean of observed values is just as good as using the model.

Comment: Saturated hydraulic conductivity (Ksat) is a key input to models that simulate groundwater flow at different spatial scales. Define all jargonesque terms please, in the contrary case, it is difficult even to identify what topic is being addressed.